# Dynamic URL for Custom Http-Client - Spring-XD

Tags: spring, spring-integration, spring-xd

We have written a custom Http-client for spring XD and planning to use this custom processor for invoking different APIs. However, We have a situation where we need to invoke two different API based on the payload. Apart from using dynamic-router (which writes to a named channel) is there a way we can set the URL dynamically for the http-client to invoke? Here is the current configuration.

```
<header-filter input-channel="input" output-channel="inputX"
    header-names="x-death" />

<service-activator input-channel="inputX" ref="gw" />

<gateway id="gw" default-request-channel="toHttp"
    default-reply-timeout="0" error-channel="errors" />

<beans:bean id="inputfields"
    class="com.batch.httpclient.HTTPInputProperties">
    <beans:property name="nonRetryErrorCodes" value="${nonRetryErrorCodes}" />
</beans:bean>
<beans:bean id="responseInterceptor"
    class="com.batch.httpclient.ResponseInterceptor">
    <beans:property name="inputProperties" ref="inputfields" />
</beans:bean>

<chain input-channel="errors" output-channel="output">

    <transformer ref="responseInterceptor" />
</chain>


<int-http:outbound-gateway id='batch-http'
    header-mapper="headerMapper" request-channel='toHttp' url-expression="${url}"
    http-method="${httpMethod}" expected-response-type='java.lang.String'
    charset='${charset}' reply-timeout='${replyTimeout}' reply-channel='output'>
</int-http:outbound-gateway>

<beans:bean id="headerMapper"
    class="org.springframework.integration.http.support.DefaultHttpHeaderMapper"
    factory-method="outboundMapper">
    <beans:property name="outboundHeaderNames" value="*" />
    <beans:property name="userDefinedHeaderPrefix" value="" />
</beans:bean>

<channel id="output" />
<channel id="input" />
<channel id="inputX" />
<channel id="toHttp" />
```

Answer (score 0):

If it's based on the payload type, something like this should work...

```
url-expression="payload.getClass().getSimpleName().equals("Bar") ? 'http://foo/bar' : 'http://foo/baz'"
```

If it's a property on the payload, then

```
url-expression="payload.foo.equals("bar") ? 'http://foo/bar' : 'http://foo/baz'"
```

**EDIT**

or

```
url-expression="payload.foo.equals("bar") ? '${url1}' : '${url2}'"
```

This would need changing the property metadata class to rename `url` and add `url2`.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Since this configuration you mentioned goes inside the context xml, Can I not reuse this custom http-client as a separate instance in a different stream for invoking a third API (for eg [link] http://foo/xyz) ? Please confirm.

Comment: That was just a sample how to be. Your `http-client` module has `url-expression="${url}"`, so, for different stream instances you should use different `--url` option values.

Comment: If you enhance the property metadata as well, you can add the other url as a property too - see my edit.